# CL-OPENGL: "Aborted" on translate

Tags: opengl, common-lisp, sbcl

While writing a simple game using SBCL, CL-OPENGL, and Lispbuilder-SDL, I can across a strange error. Soon after I got the game working, I decided to clean out all my debugging cruft (print statements, etc). I did so, but when I ran the game afterwards I received the message "Aborted" and my entire Lisp process died, with no other error message and no debugger prompt. Using print statements I managed to isolate the problem to a call to gl:translate. The strange thing is, if I put a break statement before that line and attempt to single-step, I receive no error and the code runs fine. Seems like a race condition almost, but I'm not using threads. Any ideas?

EDIT: It appears that the call to gl:translate isn't the problem. If I do something like the following:

```
(print 'first)
(print 'second)
(gl:translate ...)
```

I get the output

```
FIRST
Aborted
```

Like I said, I'm not using threads.

EDIT 2:
It works in CLisp.

EDIT 3:
Nevermind, it doesn't.

Comment: The most likely cause is heap corruption caused by passing incorrect pointers to a foreign functions.  Giving specific advice is hard without seeing the code, but I'd revise all FFI invocations carefully to check for possible pointer/memory management problems.

Comment: I'm not directly using any foreign functions, so if this is the reason it's a bug in CL-OPENGL.

Comment: Additionally, Valgrind isn't showing any output. By that I mean that after the "Aborted", there is nothing else, the program just exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by switching back to pure SDL, which is disappointing, but it works.